# How do i get a user to pick a number in c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11

i am trying to make the user pick a number thats leads to a another code in c++ how do i do that?

```
cout << "Choose a text: "
getline(????)

1:
code number one

2.
text number 2
```

Comment: What do you mean "leads to another code"? Do you mean the user picks a line number and the code at that line executes? Do you mean if the user picks a certain value, some code is executed, or otherwise some other code is executed?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a number? 
I would assume you are talking about inputing a integer.
getline mostly is used for a string and spaces between each words, or a word.
For example if the input is like "Happy thanks giving" 
the code would be like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //to use getline(cin, variable_name)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string sentenceWithSpace;
     cout << "get input" << endl;
     getline(cin,sentenceWithSpace);
     cout << sentenceWithSpace << endl;
     system("pause"); // include this line if you use VS
     return 0;
}
```

if the user is just inputing a value like 1,2,3,4,5,6

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int thisIsJustAInteger;
     cout << "get input" << endl;
     cin >> thisIsJustAInteger;
     cout << thisIsJustAInteger << endl;
     system("pause"); // include this line if you use VS
     return 0;
}
```